Apply library override values to the source
I would like to link a scene, or collection, from one blender file to another, but with the possibility to edit its content in the new blender file (only move object positions) and then transfer these edits to the source blender file.
You can edit linked things via library override, but these edits are then only saved in the new blender file and not applied to the source. I would rather have the option of applying these changes to the source.
Is there a way to apply the changed values of the Library Override to the source? Or is there another way to edit object positions and parameters of a blender file via another blender file?
Many thanks in advance!

I use library overrides frequently.  AFAIK, overrides/edits only go into the "file B", the linked file is supposed to be your static, reusable reference; just as in programming where you "include libraries".  You can make changes to your library, referenced file directly that will be updated into "file B'.  It's supposed to be a one-way linkage, not bidirectional.  Perhaps you can edit your question to show your motivation for "copying back into the library", and you might get some suggestions.

Oh I see, thank you! Then I will edit my question

You might have to use a rather clumbsy workflow like: 1) edit the object in file-B, then 2) Object::Relationships::Make_Local to break the link, then 3) open file-A and delete that object and File::Append::Object copy back from file-B.  Ugly workflow!

Oh, yeah, that's a really clumsy workflow. Hmm, I'll have to think of something else then. Thanks anyway!

I always go back to the referenced (library, linked) file to edit meshes or armature.  In fact you'll see an Edit Linked Library pane in the Item panel that is a shortcut back to the library file item (select a linked object first).   That is the assumed workflow; in the lib file you'll see a dual Return to Original File button.  you then sometimes have to use the context menu Library Override :: Troubleshoot :: Resync in the outliner if your changes are stubborn to appear.
